# Is the Mercury Programming Language used in the field?

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, industry, logic-programming

I've strong interests in Functional and Logic programming and Mercury seems like a good blend of the two. Is it used in industry at all? I'm one to learn a language just for the fun of it but it would nice to have practical, employable avenues for it. I could not find much in the way of examples of use in industry on the [language website](https://mercurylang.org/index.html).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mercury is a souped up Prolog, but logic languages are very niche in the industry, and moreso than functional languages. Dynamic scripting languages like Python, Ruby, and PHP, and languages like Java and C# will dominate most of what employers are looking for. The landscape seems different in Europe and Australia, but only slightly.

That said, there are companies that use Mercury, though I only know of two: [YesLogic](http://yeslogic.com/), which makes [PrinceXML](http://www.princexml.com/). They are located in Australia. The other is [Mission Critical IT](http://www.missioncriticalit.com/), which is based in Brussels and Australia.

Searches on major job sites like indeed.com, glassdoor.com, monster.com, and also on careers.stackoverflow.com did not turn up Mercury-specific jobs.

However, having skills with Mercury, you can probably parlay them into working at places where Prolog has been traditionally used, like in AI.

But I think the language will mostly be niche, like Haskell. There will be a few companies here and there using it, but the interest will remain strongly in academia and research.

Comment: This is true, the number of companies using Mercury that we're (the Mercury team) are aware of is three.  (As well as the two above there is now opturion.com).